# Fisher Information in Statistical Mechanics

Tags: statistical-mechanics, hamiltonian, information, statistics, partition-function

I am studying the canonical ensemble and it seems to me there is an analogy between derivatives of the partition function, which can extract energy momenta for the system and Fisher score /information.

In partciular we have expressions like $-\partial_\beta log(Z)=<H>$, $\frac{1}{Z}\partial^2_\beta Z=<H^2>$ and finally $\partial^2_\beta log(Z)= Var(H)$ where $Z$ is the partition function $\beta$ the inverse temperature.

Hence I think one could identify the fisher score of the ensemble with the log of ther partition fucntion. Anyway I cannot get further in this analogy nor can get physical meaning and interpretation of this porcess.

Any help would be great!

Comment: I won't comment on relations with Fisher information, but want to stress that there is nothing particularly remarkable about this property of $\log Z$. Indeed, by its very definition, it coincides (up to a trivial additive constant) with the standard [cumulant-generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant#Definition) of $H$.

Answer (score 2):

There are very useful relations indeed, which I wouldn't necessarily call analogies.

We define a set of thermodynamic variables denoted as {${\theta_i}$} and specify the partition function denoted as $Z(\theta)$. In a typical case where we work with Gibbs measures, we may write

$$lnZ = \psi $$

where $\psi$ corresponds to free entropy. Amusingly, the second derivative of free entropy $$\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial\theta_{m}\partial\theta_{n}}$$ yields the *thermodynamic tensor*, which is identical to Fisher information matrix $F_{mn}$, where

$$F_{mn}(\theta) = \sum_x{p(x)\frac{\partial lnp(x)}{\partial \theta_{m}}}{\frac{\partial lnp(x)}{\partial \theta_{n}}}.$$

This shows how Fisher information is immediately related to our study of statistical mechanics as your question addresses. Identification of Fisher values informs us about how a system behaves in transitions, for example.